# how to Get sharePoint edit panel properties for document in spfx

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, web-parts, spfx

how to edit  properties for document in sharepoint SPFX? inside a webpart.
Is it possible to do something like in the image I added?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HI95B.png)

Answer (score 0):

We can create custom property pane controls to achieve it. The following code examples for your reference.

[Creating a property pane for editing items in your SPFx web parts](https://github.com/juliemturner/Public-Samples/tree/master/SPFXItemProperty)

[Custom property pane controls built in React](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-custompropertypanecontrols)

Comment: Thank you @LZ_MSFT for your answer. but I didn't find the solution of what i was looking for.